# app about remove duplicate photos from photos app

Tags: ios, objective-c, duplicates, photos, removeclass

I am creating an Application that fetches Images from the photo library of the phone and remove duplicate images from it.I searched a lot but did not find any way to delete the image from the photo library.

Comment: give me idea that from where i can start from

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried? What programming language?

Comment: not tried anything yet. i m using obj-c.

Answer (score 1):

i create on demo for that 
here is the code
i used UIImageJPEGRepresentation to convert image into data.and compare them it gives me result.is there any other image property that we can compare?

```
UIImage *img1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.jpg"];
    UIImage *img2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.jpg"];

    NSData *data1 = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img1, 1.0);
    NSLog(@"%@",data1);
    NSData *data2 = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img2, 1.0);
    NSLog(@"%@",data2);
    if ([data1 isEqualToData:data2])
    {
        NSLog(@"yes");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"no");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As you know we dont have access to modify anything out side the sandbox.So before ios 8 it was not possible to delete photos from photo library.But in ios 8 and later versions are supported to delete photos from library but before removing it will ask user that you want to delete photos.If user allow then photos will be deleted.
I providing you the CODE which I have used in my app to delete photo from photo library.

```
if (check system version >= 8.0)
{

   PHPhotoLibrary *library = [PHPhotoLibrary sharedPhotoLibrary];
  [library performChanges:^{

     PHFetchResult *assetsToBeDeleted = [PHAsset fetchAssetsWithALAssetURLs:delet
                                                                   options:nil];

     [PHAssetChangeRequest deleteAssets:assetsToBeDeleted];

} completionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
     //do something here when error
 }];
}
```

Where **delet** is the array of asset url of images you get from library with help of AssetLibrary framework.

Comment: Do not check the iOS version. That's not the proper way to check for `PHPhotoLibrary`.

Comment: but for how to compare two images and fing that is it duplicate image or two different image?

Comment: i am creating app that find duplicate images from photos and remove duplicate image and only 1 image remain.

Comment: Harshit for that you have to use some mat lab algorithsm that are in c or c++ to compare pixels of photos and on that basis you will get result.Find out duplication photos fixer in mac app store.it is working on the same concept.We can write c or c++ in ios app too.

Answer (score 0):

```
PHFetchResult *moments = [PHAssetCollection fetchMomentsWithOptions:nil];        

for (PHAssetCollection *moment in moments) 
{
    PHFetchResult *assetsFetchResults = [PHAsset fetchAssetsInAssetCollection:moment options:nil];

    for (PHAsset *asset in assetsFetchResults)
    {
        // Do something with assets, for example add them to array.
    }
}
```

Comment: ty this helps me. but after getting assets how i will compare them?.i mean i am finding duplicate photos and remove duplicate and make it one.

Comment: how can i delete multiple Assets that user select?